# How to show that the following sequence is bounded and decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a bounded sequence $a_i$ and another sequence such that for each $j \in \mathbb N$ we have $b_j = \mathrm {sup} \{a_i: \ i \ge j \}$. How to show that $b_j$ is a bounded and decreasing sequence?

I presume that I can use induction to show that the sequence is bounded and decreasing but I do not know how to set the base cases and the inductive hypotheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the number of elements of the set you take the upper bound from is getting fewer elements with each increase of $j$. so the sequence of upper bounds will not increase, it can only decrease. (note that it may be constant if $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is constant)